# jQuery Validation not working on all fields

Tags: html, css, validation, jquery

### See here: **http://jsfiddle.net/zYcJm/**

The jQuery should be validating each field to check if they contain text and also if the email is valid. But:

- Validation for the message (id=message) doesn't seem to work, if you click send with nothing in the message box you do not get an error, but you should.
- If you enter an invalid input and click send and then change your input to make it valid the Send button remains unclickable.

Where are the problems in my code?

Comment: your `textarea` have a white space, did u see that ?

Comment: @RicardoArruda Great! It solves the problem.

Comment: Thankyou @RicardoArruda that fixes the problem where the message validation did not show, but still the submit button remains unclickable if you have clicked it with invalid data in the fields

Comment: Nevermind, the second problem seems to happen on jsfiddle but not on my server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You leave a white space in your `textarea`

`<textarea name="message" placeholder="your message here" id="message" class="message"> </textarea>`

try to fix this and the problem should be solve.

Answer (score 0):

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#contactForm #submit').click(function() {
        // Fade in the progress bar
        $('#contactForm #formProgress').hide();
        $('#contactForm #formProgress').html('<img src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/16640285/ajax-loader.gif" /> Sending&hellip;');
        $('#contactForm #formProgress').fadeIn();

        // Disable the submit button
        $('#contactForm #submit').attr("disabled", "disabled");

        // Clear and hide any error messages
        $('#contactForm .formError').html('');

        // Set temaprary variables for the script
        var isFocus = 0;
        var isError = 0;

        // Get the data from the form
        //    var name=$('#contactForm #name').val();
        var email = $('#contactForm #email').val();
        //    var subject=$('#contactForm #subject').val();
        var message = $('message').val();

        // Validate the data
        //    if(name=='') {
        //    $('#contactForm #errorName').html('This is a required field.');
        //        $('#contactForm #name').focus();
        //        isFocus=1;
        //        isError=1;
        //    }
        if (email == '') {

            $('#contactForm #errorEmail').html('Please enter your email address.');
            if (isFocus == 0) {
                $('#contactForm #email').focus();
                isFocus = 1;
            }
            isError = 1;
        } else {
            var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
            if (reg.test(email) == false) {
                $('#contactForm #errorEmail').html('Please enter a valid email address.');
                if (isFocus == 0) {
                    $('#contactForm #email').focus();
                    isFocus = 1;
                }
                isError = 1;
            }
        }

        if (message ==  null || message == '') {

            $('#contactForm #errorMessage').html('This is a required field.');
            if (isFocus == 0) {
                $('#contactForm #message').focus();
                isFocus = 1;
            }
            isError = 1;
        }

        // Terminate the script if an error is found
        if (isError == 1) {
            $('#contactForm #formProgress').html('');
            $('#contactForm #formProgress').hide();

            // Activate the submit button
            $('#contactForm #submit').attr("disabled", "");

            return false;
        }

        $.ajaxSetup({
            cache: false
        });

        var dataString = //'name='+ name + '&
        'email=' + email + //'&subject=' + subject + 
        '&message=' + message;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/16640285/submit-form-ajax.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(msg) {

                //alert(msg);
                // Check to see if the mail was successfully sent
                if (msg == 'Mail sent') {
                    // Update the progress bar
                    $('#contactForm #formProgress').html('<img src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/16640285/ajax-complete.gif" /> Message sent.').delay(2000).fadeOut(400);

                    // Clear the subject field and message textbox
                    //    $('#contactForm #subject').val('');
                    $('#contactForm #message').val('');
                } else {
                    $('#contactForm #formProgress').html('');
                    alert('There was an error sending your email. Please try again.');
                }

                // Activate the submit button
                $('#contactForm #submit').attr("disabled", "");
            },
            error: function(ob, errStr) {
                $('#contactForm #formProgress').html('');
                alert('There was an error sending your email. Please try again.');

                // Activate the submit button
                $('#contactForm #submit').attr("disabled", "");
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});​
```

paste this one and check buddyyyyyyyy